# Why won't BootstrapVue Render?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I recently used npm to install BootstrapVue with:
`npm install vue bootstrap-vue bootstrap`

I then included BootstrapVue into the root of my project like so:

```
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

Finally, this is the template I am using to test the BootstrapVue component:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <search-bar />
      <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
          <post :postData="post" />
      </div>
      <b-button pill >TEST</b-button>
  </div>
</template>
```

When I go to check the web page, the button appears, but it renders with no styling. The strange thing is that when I check the Vue dev tools extension, the BButton component is recognized and contains all the styling properties included (in this case, just the "pill" option set to true). I even inspect the button element on the DOM and it contains the classes that were passed down from BootstrapVue, but none of those styles were rendered. What am I missing here?

Also, just for good measure, I looked in the package.json file to make sure Bootstrap and BootstrapVue were installed and were up to date. They are.

Comment: In docs, they explicitly import Bootstrap and BootstrapVue CSS files https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/#using-module-bundlers

Comment: @artanki That's what I get for skimming the docs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

in your root of your project(app.js), you will need to add 2 more lines

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
```

To import the css files